# HTML and css related with media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to create a footer nav for screens sizes with 768 or more (tablet sized). I finished my mobile first approach with the footer nav but with the next size up I want to add more list items in the nav. how do I do that without them also being in my mobile first layout?

Comment: Please reword for better clarity. Also include some code and what you have already tried and have working.

Answer (score 0):

1. First add the lists and then give it an Id or class
2. Then in your css code, use the id or class and set its visibility  = "hidden"

   ## list { visibility: "hidden"}
3. Now write your media query and set visibility = "visible"
   @media screen and (min-width: 768px) { #lists { visibility: "visible"} }